# How to get value from choices in Django?

Tags: django

How to get a value from choices and display it on a form in Django?
In this case (as in the picture), so that *English* is displayed, not *en*

[Picture of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrKof.png)

In the template I print the form as a variable `{{ form }}`. I also tried to output by one field `{{ form.language.get_lang_display }}`, but in this case the language field is not displayed at all.

File **models.py**

```
class AvailableLanguage(models.Model):
    LANGUAGES = (
        ('en', 'English'),
        ('ru', 'Russian'),
    )
    lang = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, choices=LANGUAGES)
    lang_code = models.CharField(max_length=5, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()


class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    language = models.ForeignKey(AvailableLanguage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
    body = models.TextField()
    ...
```

File **forms.py**

```
class UserQuestion(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('title', 'language', 'body')
```

File **add_question.html**

```
{% block content %}
    <form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{#        {{ form }}#}
        {{ form.language.get_lang_display }} {#Not displayed#}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input class="btn--primary" type="submit" value="{% trans 'Создать' %}">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please add your forms.py code.

Comment: Could you add your HTML template too ?

Comment: Added code to question

Comment: Why do you have a `Language` model if you restrict the languages choices in this model ??? Either you have a fixed set of available languages and then you don't need this model at all (just make `Question.language` a charfield with `LANGUAGES` as choices), or you want available languages to be runtime-editable and then you don't want to restrict `AvailableLanguage.lang`.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, thank you for such a question. I use the Question model to add a question to the site from the Available Languages of the AvailableQuestion model. At the same time, AvailableQuestion is also used for internationalization. I do not know if I did it right. Perhaps your answer is correct. I will try to deal with this.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, In the future, I think, to make a non-fixed data set of the AvailableQuestion model.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just return a str function from your **AvailableLanguage** model:

```
class AvailableLanguage(models.Model):
    LANGUAGES = (
        ('en', 'English'),
        ('ru', 'Russian'),
        )
    lang = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, choices=LANGUAGES)
    lang_code = models.CharField(max_length=5, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_lang_display()
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
{{ form.get_lang_display }}
```

instead of

```
{{ form.language.get_lang_display }}
```